# Django pagination not working. Object list is rendering items but not dividing into pages

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm currently working on an e-commerce site and I'm trying to create a product list page that spans into another page after 4 items have been displayed. rendering the page doesn't produce any error but all items in the database are displayed on the same page and remains the same even after switching to another page.

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Item
from django.core.paginator import Paginator   


def item_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    items = Item.objects.filter(available=True)

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        items = items.filter(category=category)

    paginator = Paginator(items, 4)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request,
                  'item/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'page_obj': page_obj,
                   'items': items})
```

my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.item_list, name='item_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.item_list, name='item_list'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
]
```

pagination snippet from the template

```
<nav class="d-flex justify-content-center wow fadeIn">
        <ul class="pagination pg-blue">

          <!--Arrow left-->
          {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
          {% endif %}
            <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>
          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
 </nav>
```

and the logic that displays the products

```
<div class="row wow fadeIn">

          <!--Grid column-->
          {% for item in items %}
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

            <!--Card-->
            <div class="card" style="width: 16rem; height: 25rem">

              <!--Card image-->
              <div class="view overlay">
                <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">
                  {% if item.tags and item.label %}
                  <div class="imgHolder">
                    <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="img-fluid">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill {{ item.get_label_display }}-color">{{ item.tags }}</span>
                  </div>
                  {% else %}
                  <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="img-fluid">
                  {% endif %}
                </a>
                <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">
                  <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <!--Card image-->

              <!--Card content-->
              <div class="card-body text-center" style="height: 9rem;">
                <!--Category & Title-->
                <a href="{{ item.category.get_absolute_url }}" class="grey-text">
                  <h5>{{ item.category.name|truncatechars:20 }}</h5>
                </a>
                <h5>
                  <strong style="color:red">
                    <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
                  </strong>
                </h5>

                <h6 class="font-weight-bold">
                  {% if item.discount_price %}
                  <strong><del>${{ item.price}}</del></strong>
                  <strong>${{ item.discount_price }}</strong>
                  {% else %}
                  <strong>${{ item.price }}</strong>
                  {% endif %}
                </h6>

              </div>
              <!--Card content-->

            </div>
            <!--Card-->
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong and I'm also open to alternative means of solving the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using all the queryset that you are passing to the paginator. You must iterate over the page_obj.object_list.

```
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
page_obj_items = page_obj.object_list
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to loop throw {% for item in page_obj %}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).